# Custom DataAnnotation attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

When I use DisplayAttribute in ASP.NET MVC 3 models it quickly becomes a pain writing them because we have to either hardcode the string or reference the string from a some static class that contains `const strings` (which is what  I have now, see below). But even that is too much for me.

I would like to come up with an attribute that would be called something like [SimpleDisplay] and it would implicitly construct the string for resources by looking at

1. class name,
2. property name that the attribute is attached to.

Is this possible?

Something like this

```
public class Product {

 [SimpleDisplay] // it will take Product and Name and do something like this Product_Name
 public string Name { get; set; } 

}
```

This is what I want to get rid of, if possible:

```
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Localize), Name = ResourceStrings.product_prettyid)]
    public virtual int PrettyId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Localize), Name = ResourceStrings.product_name)]
    public virtual string Title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Now I know that it is not possible to inherit the DisplayAttribute cause it's sealed. What other options I have? Does it even make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try creating just a standard attribute and custom **[DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dataannotationsmodelmetadataprovider.aspx)**. You can override **CreateMetadata** method, which gets `IEnumerable<Attribute>`. You should than search for your attribute

```
attributes.OfType<SimpleDisplayAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
```

and populate model metadata in any way you want.

Comment: Thanks, this is the right and best way. More details on your approach are outlined here http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2010/06/14/asp.net-mvc-localization-displaynameattribute-alternatives-a-better-way.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If i have a correct understanding what you mean, you may just create a simple custom attribute like this one:

```
public class LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute {
    public LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute(string expression) : base(expression) { }

    public override string DisplayName {
        get {
            try {
                string[] vals = base.DisplayName.Split(',');
                if(vals != null && vals.Length == 2)
                    return (string)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(vals[0].Trim(), vals[1].Trim());
            } catch {}
            return "{res:" + base.DisplayName + "}";
        }
    }
}
```

You may then use it as an attribute on your properies. MVC HTML extensions will pickup your custom attribute.

```
[LocalizedDisplayName("LBL, lbl_name1")]
public string[] Name1 { get; set; }
```

Comment: that does nothing to ease the incorporation of attributes to the properties. In fact, it complicates things because it relies again on hardcoded parameters instead of no parameters (or strong typed ones).